# ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option (While trying to drop DEFAULT on a COLUMN)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I was trying to drop DEFAULT constraint on COLUMN sal i.e. salary in customer table in Oracle Database.

SQL statement which I tried was

```
ALTER TABLE customer ALTER COLUMN sal DROP DEFAULT;
```

Error message which I received was

```
ALTER TABLE customer ALTER COLUMN sal DROP DEFAULT
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can anyone tell me the mistake which I am doing?

Comment: And by default constraint you mean what exactly? Column's default value(not constraint by the way)? Or something else? If you want to remove previously specified default value for a column. Just set it to NULL. `alter table customer modify sal default null;`

Comment: Where [**in the manual**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm) did you find that syntax? A default value is not a "constraint", it's a default.

Comment: Besides the syntax error, which has already been explained, you are making another, more serious mistake. Before you post here, try doing a little research on your own. Google "Oracle change column default" or something like this; if you can't find the correct answer within a couple minutes, **then** post a question here. Posting here directly shows no effort on your part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this query :

```
ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY sal DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: "try this qury" isn't really an explanation why the OP's problem occurs and why your statement should work. I thinl "query" isn't the right term for your statement

Comment: @miracle173 - perhaps you are right in general, but in this case it is obvious even without any explanation that the OP's attempt had syntax mistakes. The responder here provided the correct syntax. What's your objection?

Comment: @batnight your solution has worked. I wanted to figure out is there any way by which we can remove default value which we have set for a column in a table. Setting it back to null is a good way.

Comment: @mathguy e.g. the OP seems to confuse constraints with default values. This can be clarified. A link to the manual that describes the correct syntax could also be useful.